# How do I prevent Windows Media Player from using a temporary file when playing video from an HTTP server?

Tags: http, windows-mobile, video-streaming

I've been having some trouble with Windows Media Player on CE 5.0 downloading an entire multi-megabyte movie file from a web server into a temporary directory and running the device out of memory.  Any idea how to force the player to play in streaming mode?

Comment: What is the media type and format of compression?

Comment: It varies.  Sometimes it's MPEG, sometimes WMV.

Comment: Never mind -- Windows Media Player turned out to be something of a red herring.  I'm still trying to isolate the problem, but it seems to be a weird corner case in which MSHTML is downloading multiple copies of resources that should already be in its cache, growing it without bound and disregarding the cache size limit.